# IsoDep/apdu communication commands descriptions?

Tags: java, android, nfc, apdu, ndef

How do you know how to communicate via the isoDep/apdu with android, any rules or documentation about it?

There are basic descriptions available, but there is nothing mentioned about what to put in `.transcieve()`  to communicate with your `NFC chip`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/IsoDep.html

http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/DM00103491.pdf

Sometimes there are shown at specific chip documentations, but it is not a standard.

In general I have chip which TAG output indicate it handles following technologies:

```
NDEF
NFCA
IsoDep
```

NDEF is standard described and available via android API, but how to work with eg `IsoDep`?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Most contactless smartcards use ISO/IEC 7816-4 APDUs to communicate over ISO-DEP. So have a look at the ISO/IEC 7816-4 standard. It describes the APDU format, a basic file system structure as well as a set of commands for access  to files and data structures, for management of logical communication channels, and for securing the communication. However, it is up to a card (and its protocol specification) which of these commands (and possibly which additional (proprietary) commands it supports).

Specifications of such protocols are, *for instance*:

- EMV Contactless Specifications for Payment Systems (see http://www.emvco.com/)
- ICAO Doc 9303 Part 1 - Machine Readable Passports. Volume 2 - Specifications for Electronically Enabled Passports with Biometric Identification Capability (see http://www.icao.int/)
- NFC Forum Type 4 Tag Operation specification (see http://nfc-forum.org/)

Some contactless cards support proprietary (non-APDU) protocols over ISO-DEP (either instead or in addition to an APDU-based protocol). An example for this is MIFARE DESFire (EV1) which supports three protocols:

1. the proprietary DESFire native command set,
2. the proprietary DESFire native command set wrapped into APDUs, and
3. a subset of the ISO/IEC 7816-4 command set.

In your specific case, Android reports that the tag supports the three technologies `NfcA`, `IsoDep` and `Ndef`. This is a clear indication that the tag implements the NFC Forum Type 4 Tag Operation specification in order to be recognized as an NDEF tag. Therefore, you can exchange the APDUs described in that specification when talking to the tag directly over ISO-DEP.

Note that the tag might implement other protocols/commands as well. You can only find out by either *knowing* what the tag supports or by *testing* certain commands/protocols with it.